# How can I stop my iPod connecting to my computer when I plug it in?

Tags: ipod, windows, charging

Seems like a strange question, but here is the situation: when I arrive at work, I want to recharge my iPod. The easiest way to do that is via the USB connection on my computer.

But if I plug it in, I have the minor irritation that the iPod goes straight to the **Do not disconnect** screen (interrupting playback). I then have to go to the **Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media** option in Windows (Windows 7) to get what I really want: the iPod just charging as if plugged in to the mains.

Is there a simple way to prevent this? I don't have (or want) iTunes installed.

Comment: As the solution is not within the iPod, nor you want iTunes, nor you're using a Mac, I'd say this is not the appropriated forum for this question.

Comment: @Thecafremo: I don't know whether the solution is not within the iPod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but it isn't possible from just a configuration change.  Neither the iPod nor Windows have options to not mount it.

I had the same requirement and ended up making my own USB cable that only passed the power but not the data connections.  If you look around online, you can find the same thing for sale for only a few dollars

Answer (score 2):

Without installing iTunes, and configuring it not to sync automatically, the only options are power cable related:

- purchase a charge only cable such as [Logic3 USB Charger Cable for iPod](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logic3-USB-Charger-Cable-iPod/dp/B00070HKV0)
- purchase a powered USB hub and don't connect it to anything, just use it to charge the iPod (which is basically a cheap USB charger)
- purchase a stand alone iDevice charger